# MBProgressHUD not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

In my app, I am loading a resource heavy view that takes about 1 to 2 seconds to load. So I am loading it in a separate thread like this:

```
hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
[hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadWorkbench:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

however it never appears, and application looks frozen to the end user. any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It does not appear because you never tell add the HUD as a subview of the window. try something like:

```
    // Should be initialized with the windows frame so the HUD disables all user input by covering the entire screen
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    // Add HUD to screen
    [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];

    // Register for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;

    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading Workbench", nil);
    HUD.detailsLabelText = NSLocalizedString(@"please wait", nil);

    // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadWorkbench:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Since you are setting yourself as the HUD delegate, also add the following delegate method:

```
- (void)hudWasHidden {
    // Remove HUD from screen 
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];

    // add here the code you may need

}
```

and remember to add `MBProgressHUDDelegate` in the corresponding header file.

Comment: oops, actually i had written the code in the question from the top of my head. I am doing all of it (adding subview to window, setting delegate), it doesn’t work. (I am editing the question to fix the sample code)

Comment: this is really bizarre, I have had exact same code except that i had a line that looked like this: HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];, I changed initWithView to initWithWindow and it started to work. may be I made the mistake somewhere else